# Cache Optimization - Hashmap vs QuickSort?

Tags: arrays, caching, hashmap, big-o

Suppose that I have N unsorted arrays, of integers. I'd like to find the intersection of those arrays.

There are two good ways to approach this problem.

One, I can sort the arrays in place with an nlogn sort, like QuickSort or MergeSort. Then I can put a pointer at the start of each array. Compare each array to the one below it, iterating the pointer of whichever array[pointer] is smaller, or if they're all equal, you've found an intersection.

This is an O(nlogn) solution, with constant memory (since everything is done in-place).

The second solution is to use a hash map, putting in the values that appear in the first array as keys, and then incrementing those values as you traverse through the remaining arrays (and then grabbing everything that had a value of N). This is an O(n) solution, with O(n) memory, where n is the total size of all of the arrays.

Theoretically, the former solution is o(nlogn), and the latter is O(n). However, hash maps do not have great locality, due to the way that items can be randomly scattered through the map, due to collisions. The other solution, although o(nlogn), traverses through the array one at a time, exhibiting excellent locality. Since a CPU will tend to pull the array values from memory that are next to the current index into the cache, the O(nlogn) solution will be hitting the cache much more often than the hash map solution.

Therefore, given a significantly large array size (as number of elements goes to infinity), is it feasible that the o(nlogn) solution is actually faster than the O(n) solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For integers you can use a non-comparison sort (see [counting, radix sort](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/11_2_Counting_Sort_Radix_So.html)). A large set might be encoded, e.g. sequential runs into ranges. That would compress the data set and allow for skipping past large blocks (see [RoaringBitmaps](https://github.com/lemire/RoaringBitmap)). There is the potential to be hardware friendly and have O(n) complexity.

Complexity theory does not account for constants. As you suspect there is always the potential for an algorithm with a higher complexity to be faster than the alternative, due to the hidden constants. By exploiting the nature of the problem, e.g. limiting the solution to integers, there are potential optimizations not available to general purpose approach. Good algorithm design often requires understanding and leveraging those constraints.